# Inverting (via Taylor expansion) a sum of (rank-deficient) skew-symmetric matrix and (rank-deficient) Diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis, matrix-inverse, perturbation-theory

I have the following problem:
A matrix $C\in \mathbb{R}^{2N}$, where 
$C=\epsilon A+D$

$\epsilon A=(C-C')/2$ is skew symmetric with "block" anti-diagonal structure of size 4.

$ D=(C+C')/2$ (Diagonal matrix) with "block" diagonal structure of size 2.

$D=\begin{bmatrix}
    0       & 0 & 0 & \dots  \\
    0       & 0 & 0 & \dots  \\
    0 & 0 & \alpha & \dots \\
   0 & 0 & 0& \alpha & \dots \\
   0 & 0 & 0& 0 & 2\alpha \dots \\
0 & 0 & 0& 0 & 0& 2\alpha \dots\\
\vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0& 0 & 0& \dots &(N-1)\alpha &0\\
0 & 0 & 0& 0 & 0& 0& \dots &(N-1)\alpha 
  \end{bmatrix}$

And

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
    0       & 0 & 0 & -\beta \dots  \\
    0       & 0 & \beta & \dots  \\
    0 & -\beta & 0 & 0&0&-\sqrt{2}\beta\dots \\
   \beta & 0 & 0& 0 & \sqrt{2}\beta&\dots \\
   0 & 0 & 0& -\sqrt{2}\beta & 0 \dots \\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{2}\beta& 0 & 0& 0 \dots\\
\vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0& 0 &\dots&-\sqrt{N-1}\beta&0 &0\\
0 & 0 & 0&\dots \sqrt{N-1}\beta& 0& 0&  &0 
  \end{bmatrix}$

Here $\alpha,\beta$ are constants of order 1.

I want to expand the inverse of $C$ in terms of $\epsilon$<<1, by writing

$C^{-1}=(D+\epsilon A)^{-1}$.

Note that both $D$ and $A$ are of rank $2N-2$.

Due to rank-deficiency of $D$, I cannot simply invert $D$ and do the obvious Taylor series.

Does any one have any ideas on how to proceed in this ?

The difficulty seems to be due to differently sized "block"-wise structures of $A$ and $D$.

For example, if instead the matrix $A$ was "block"-anti-diagonal of size 2 (same as block size of $D$), it seems like the Taylor series gives the right result where I replace $D^{-1}$ with pseudo-inverse and only invert in the non-singular subspace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just an idea.

I think the best way to start is to expand on the structure of the matrices $D, C$. For example, $D$ can be readily seen to be expressible in the form $$\alpha M_1\otimes I_2=\alpha\begin{bmatrix}
0  & \mathbf{0}^T\\
\mathbf{0}  &  J
\end{bmatrix}\otimes I_2$$ where $J=diag(1,2,,\cdots)$. I think the structure of matrix $A$ can be expressed as $\beta M_2\otimes B$ where $$M_2=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots\\
1 & 0 & \sqrt{2} & 0 & \cdots\\
0 &  \sqrt{2} & 0 &  \sqrt{3}  & \cdots\\
0& 0 &  \sqrt{3} & 0 & \cdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots\end{bmatrix},\\B=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$ Now the problem becomes finding $(\epsilon\beta M_2\otimes B+\alpha M_1\otimes I_2 )^{-1}.$